# Artifactory archive deposit doesn't extract

Tags: artifactory

I'm attempting to upload a moderately large file system as a 73 gb zip file using curl to my org's artifactory. The goal is for it to extract and replicate the file system in artifactory.

All I can accomplish is getting the zip file on the archive, but there's no extraction of the archive. Is there a problem with my headers? I've tried both -H 'X-Explode-Archive: true" and 'X-Explode-Archive-Atomic=true'.

'X-Explode-Archive: true' resulted in

```
  "errors" : [ {
  "status" : 404,
  "message" : "Explode archive deployment failed. View log for more details."
```

However, I don't see a log file. Do I need to pipe output to create a log or specify something to get it?

For what it's worth, this is my curl call:

```
curl -H 'X-JFrog-Art-Api:<my api key goes here>' -H 'X-Explode-Archive-Atomic=true'   "https://my.orgs.artifactory.path" -T my.local.file.path.zip
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask your Artifactory admin to increase the upload size in **General Configuration**->**File Upload Max Size (MB)**